# How does a photon transform into two particles

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation

In pair production how do we know the energy of the photon is transformed into the mass of the two particles? How do we know it’s not something else similar to the photoelectric effect, where the energy of the photon interacts with the atom knocking parts off?
To be clear I am not disagreeing with experiment or saying there are no pair productions. I want to know how we know for sure the exact way these pairs are produced.

Comment: We know that when matter and antimatter come into contact, they annihilate to produce photons. Since the laws governing this interaction are time reversal symmetric, we can run this interaction backwards, and we'll get photons of high enough energy producing matter and antimatter. I didn't really understand the second part of your question, though. What relations are you making between electrons in an atom being excited and pair production?

Comment: I think you mean "photoelectric effect" and not "electromagnetic effect". and "knocking off parts" you mean "electrons being ejected".

Comment: We know it’s what QED says it is because every experiment we do is consistent with QED’s predictions. It is the most highly verified theory in the history of physics.

Comment: @josephh Yes, thanks Joseph the photoelectric  effect what I meant.

Comment: @G.Smith I’m not disagreeing with experiment. I’m not saying there are no pair productions. The question is asking something different. It’s a reasonable question that doesn’t need to be down voted. I really am interested.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, nor have I voted to close.

Comment: why don;t you read https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2174030  .  the wikipedia article has the math,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron .  " I want to know how we know for sure the exact way these pairs are produced."  Because when a positron annihilates on an electron gamma rays of very specific energy are produced and that led to the theory seen in the wiki.,